# Need help determining what this center is isomorphic to

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am looking at this [released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F02_Final_Exam-K.Ribet_.pdf), problem 2c. It states:

> Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $8$ and $Z$ be the center of $G$. To which group is $Z$ isomorphic?

It gives a hint to recall a theorem from what I believe is this [released past midterm](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F02_Second_Midterm-K.Ribet_.pdf). I think he is referring to 4a, and 4b:

[image: 4a and 4b]

I'm still not exactly sure how to use them. As for b, $G$ is not of the form $pq$ it is $2^3$. And the first part, I'm not sure how I would fit that in.

I can "solve" it, because in the next question it is mentioned that $G/Z$ is isomorphic to Klein-4 (although I have not proven it). Hence $Z$ must have order $2$, as $G$ has order $8$ therefore $Z(G)$ divides $G$ and $8/2=4$. From this, I know there is only [one possible group of order $2$](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n), implying $Z \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

This is begging the question, as I don't know how to prove the one after this. And proving the original question would make the next question trivial.

Any hint in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: There are only two non-abelian groups of order $8$. That's the symmetry group of the square and the quaternion group consisting of the elements $\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k$ with $i^2 = j^2 =k^2 = ijk =  -1$. Check their centers, and you're done. It's a boring solution potentially demanding a few calculations, but it gets the job done.

Comment: See my answer. It's easy to conclude without the next problem that the center has order 2 as long as you know 4a.

Comment: You might want to do the same for a group of order $p^3$, $p$ a prime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: being a $p$-group, the center is nontrivial, and a group of order 2 is cyclic. What can the order of the center be?

Comment: Ok, so I think the problem is I didn't know about p-group. In this case the argument should go: Since it is non-trivial, we know that the order is $2$, $4$ or $8$, but G is not abelian so the order cannot be $8$ and $2$ is guaranteed cyclic hence $Z$ has order $2$ and $|G/Z| = 4$

Comment: No it's the opposite. By 4a the quotient can't be cyclic so the center can't have order 4.

Comment: Oh, whoops my bad, but $Z$ should have order $2$. That was me slipping up there, I didn't mean to write that, just mixed things around sorry about that. Thanks! (Modified original comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ be cyclic group. So, $\frac{G}{Z(G)}=<gZ(G)>$ for some $g\in G$. It's mean for every $x\in G$, we can find $z\in Z(G)$ such that $x=zg^n$. Now let: $a,b\in G$. So, $a=g^kz_1$ and $b=g^mz_2$ which $z_1,z_2 \in Z(G)$ and $m,k\in \mathbb Z$. Thus: $$ab=g^kz_1g^mz_2=g^kg^mz_1z_2=g^{m+k}z_2z_1=g^mg^kz_1z_2=g^mz_2g^kz_1=ba$$  Which means $G$ is an abelian group. So, $Z(G)=G$ contradiction. So, $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ when $G$ is non-abelian group, can not be cyclic.
For the prt $(b)$, because of $G$ is an non-abelian group, we have the following cases:
$(1)$  $\left|\frac{G}{Z(G)}\right|=p$
$(2)$ $\left|\frac{G}{Z(G)}\right|=q$
$(3)$ $\left|\frac{G}{Z(G)}\right|=pq$.
The cases $(1),(2)$ can not happen. Since in this cases, $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ shoud be cyclic and $G$ should be abelian group. contradict. So,the only possible  case is $(3)$  and it's mean $Z(G)$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

(a) We know from $G/Z(G)$ theorem that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. By this, in our present case, the contradiction comes clear.

(b) Given $|G|=pq$ and $G$ is nonabelian. Since $Z(G)\leq G$ so $|Z(G)|\in \{1, p, q, pq\}$. If $|Z(G)|=p$ then $|G/Z(G)|=|G|/|Z(G)|=q$ which is prime so that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic again and hence $G$ is abelian, contradiction. Similarly $|Z(G)|\neq p$. WHat if $|Z(G)|=pq$? Then $|G|=|Z(G)|$ means $G=Z(G)$ and hence G is abelian. Thus contradiction.

Hence $|Z(G)|=1$ i.e. $G$ has trivial centre.